# Отсутствие названий полей в listView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, listview

Создал `listView` код из `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listview);
Button btn = findViewById(R.id.button);
String[] names = {"Мясо","Рыба","Овощи","Фрукты","Специи"};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,names);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}
Но при этом в приложении поля имеют названия по умолчанию. Как это исправить?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вроде так и должно быть..

Comment: Даже после первого запуска..

Comment: @maks_007 То есть должны быть дефолтные значения? Я думал что сделал все правильно в этом коде указав в параметрах массив    names

Comment: Запустите на живом устройстве.

Comment: Вы запускаете в эмуляторе или на реальном устройстве? дело в том, что на скриншоте - визуальный редактор. Это не исполняемая программа, а просто картинка, как выглядит разметка, там и не должно быть названий полей из кода.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

тогда в своем коде после установки адаптера добавь `ListView listView = getListView();
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);`

Comment: Нет, это так же ничего не меняет.

Comment: Оказ.я не правильно понял вопрос..Если хотите ListView с чекбоксами то сделайте кастомный ListView.

Comment: Тоже как то делал  как сверху указал человек..Точно не помню но были проблемы..

Answer (score 0):

```
= new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);
```

Comment: Но мне нужно выбрать несколько значений. И даже при этом редактировании кода ничего не меняется.

Answer (score 0):

покажите разметку listView.
запустил ваш код и вышло примерно следующее[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ого, так оно и должно быть благодарю.Возможно у меня не все в порядке с ПК.